# Module, block or whatever to scope variables without explicitly listing them?

Tags: notebooks, scoping

In larger notebooks I have often trouble with conflicting variable names. To combat this there are Modules and blocks. But with those you always have to list the variables you are using. I don't understand the need for this. Is there an alternative where you just open a scope of some kind, and everything is local to that scope? That's a feature of  pretty much every other programming language has and I'm desperately missing.

Comment: [`Begin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Begin.html)?

Comment: it looks like there are some good solutions, more in-depth than mine, in that linked post

Answer (score 2):

[`Begin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Begin.html) may be what you need here, as it allows you to define variables inside a given [`Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html):

```
a = 3;
Begin["MyContext`"];
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};
Print@{a, b, c};
End[];
Print@{a, b, c}
Print@{MyContext`a, MyContext`b, MyContext`c}
```

> {1,2,3}
>
> {1,b,c}
>
> {MyContext`a,2,3}

There are a couple of important caveats:  If you have already given a variable a name in the `` Global` `` context, then you cannot define a variable in the new context with that exact same name.  Also, when leaving the new context, the defined variables are not cleared, for that you need to do `` ClearAll["MyContext`*"] `` after you `End[]`

Comment: I worried that this might be the best answer. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Basti Another option would be to use `Module[{x},......]` and then define every variable you need inside as a downvalue of `x`, like `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc

Comment: That's just slightly more convenient :D

Comment: @Basti The way I normally make a Module or Block is to just write all the code as I want it, then all the unscoped variables are still blue. I just add them into the brackets for the scope until there is no blue left. It doesn't take that long to do...

Comment: Yeah I get that. However it's hard to accept that things like that are so incredibly complicated. The power of Mathematica is in no relation to its usability.